# comparing 2 dictionaries list of values irrespective of identical keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

I have 2 dictionaries, say

```
dict1 = {'a': ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'], 'b': ['xxx', 'ab', 'ac', 'ed']}
dict2 = {1: ['fgh', 'yyy', 'iy'], 2: ['xxx', 'ax', 'ac', 'yyy']}
```

I want to compare each values of each keys of a dictionary with other dictionary and return the number of matching values.

For example, if I compare the values of key *'a'* of dictionary **dict1**, with dictionary **dict2**, it should return the count as *'1'*, *'2'* since value 'yyy' matches with **dict2** with key *'1'* and values *'xxx'* and *'yyy'* matches with **dict2** with key *'2'*. Similarly in the next iteration, I should compare the values of key *'b'* of dictionary **dict1** with dictionary **dict2** values

May I know, how to do this python

Comment: you mean *"...since value **`'yyy'`** matches with dict2..."*, right?

Comment: What have you attempted so far on this problem? Do you know how to check if two lists have any entries in common?

Comment: You can't use ints as keys either...

Comment: @LismUK you can but not with this syntax

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
dict1 = {'a': ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'], 'b': ['xxx', 'ab', 'ac', 'ed']}
dict2 = {1: ['fgh', 'yyy', 'iy'], 2: ['xxx', 'ax', 'ac', 'yyy']}

dict3 = {k: [len(set(v) & set(l)) for l in dict2.values()] for k, v in dict1.items()}
print(dict3)  # {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [0, 2]}
```

Note that the order is not guaranteed since dictionaries do not care about it. So the outcome could have also been `{'a': [2, 1], 'b': [0, 2]}` for example..

Maybe this variation is better:

```
dict3 = {k: {subk: len(set(v) & set(subv)) for subk, subv in dict2.items()} for k, v in dict1.items()}
print(dict3)  # {'a': {1: 1, 2: 2}, 'b': {1: 0, 2: 2}}
#                 ^key of dict1 ^         ^
#                               |         |key of dict2
#                               |count
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking you for. Thanks.

Comment: nice one liner ! efficiency gain for sure but a loose of readability.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
dict1 = {'a': ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'], 'b': ['xxx', 'ab', 'ac', 'ed']}
dict2 = {1: ['fgh', 'yyy', 'iy'], 2: ['xxx', 'ax', 'ac', 'yyy']}

results = {}

for key1 in dict1:
    results[key1] = set()  # create a new entry for each dict1's key
    for value in dict1[key1]:
        for key2 in dict2:
            if value in dict2[key2]:
                results[key1].add(key2)  # store key2 if value match

print(results)  # {'b': {2}, 'a': {1, 2}}
```